# Vagrantでpublic_networkの設定ができない

Tags: centos, vagrant, network

KVMサーバでvagrantを使って仮想マシンを作る際、ネットワークの設定を変更することができません。
目的の環境としては、vagrantで作成されたゲストに外部のサーバからアクセスしたいので
public_networkにしたいと考えております。

私の環境は下記のとおりです。
Host(KVMサーバ):CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core) 
Guest:CentOS7
vagrant:2.0.1 version
ネットワークデバイス(idにはvlanidがはいります)
デバイス      タイプ    状態      接続                
brens1f1.id  bridge    接続済み  bridge-brens1f1.id
virbr0        bridge    接続済み  virbr0              
virbr1        bridge    接続済み  virbr1              
ens1f0        ethernet  接続済み  ens1f0              
ens1f1.id    vlan      接続済み  vlan-ens1f1.id

brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
brens1f1.id     8000.a44c11deabe5   no      ens1f1.id
virbr0      8000.52540018f0be   yes     virbr0-nic
virbr1      8000.5254005c1399   yes     virbr1-nic

```ruby
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :   
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.network "public_network"
end
```

```
vagrant up --provider=libvirt
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'libvirt' provider...
/root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:44: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:44: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
==> default: Creating image (snapshot of base box volume).
==> default: Creating domain with the following settings...
==> default:  -- Name:              vagrant_default
==> default:  -- Domain type:       kvm
==> default:  -- Cpus:              1
==> default:  -- Feature:           acpi
==> default:  -- Feature:           apic
==> default:  -- Feature:           pae
==> default:  -- Memory:            512M
==> default:  -- Management MAC:    
==> default:  -- Loader:            
==> default:  -- Base box:          centos/7
==> default:  -- Storage pool:      default
==> default:  -- Image:             /var/lib/libvirt/images/vagrant_default.img (41G)
==> default:  -- Volume Cache:      default
==> default:  -- Kernel:            
==> default:  -- Initrd:            
==> default:  -- Graphics Type:     vnc
==> default:  -- Graphics Port:     5900
==> default:  -- Graphics IP:       127.0.0.1
==> default:  -- Graphics Password: Not defined
==> default:  -- Video Type:        cirrus
==> default:  -- Video VRAM:        9216
==> default:  -- Sound Type:    
==> default:  -- Keymap:            en-us
==> default:  -- TPM Path:          
==> default:  -- INPUT:             type=mouse, bus=ps2
==> default: Creating shared folders metadata...
/root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:44: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
==> default: Starting domain.
There was an error talking to Libvirt. The error message is shown
below:

Call to virDomainCreateWithFlags failed: インターフェース eth0 のインデックスを取得できません: そのようなデバイスはありません
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

私の環境の場合、
config.vm.network “public_network”, :dev => ‘br0’, :type => ‘bridge’
のようにするとうまくいきました。boxにもよると思いますが。